# If $a,b,c$ and $d$ non-zero natural number such that $ab=cd$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, natural-numbers

Question :

If $a,b,c$ and $d$ non-zero natural number such

that $ab=cd$

Show that :

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ is not prime number

My try :

Call $m$ : $\gcd$ of $a,b$ then $m|_a$ and $m|_b$

Then $\exists \alpha,\beta$ such that :

$a=m.\alpha$ and $b=m.\beta$

So $b\alpha=d\beta$

But how I complete ??

Comment: By "neutral" do you mean "natural"?

Comment: Yes , sorry sir , thanks

Comment: Note that we write $m \mid a$ for "$m$ divides $a$", not $m|_a$. Also you should use "\cdot" ($\cdot$) for multiplication, not a period. In addition, I don't see how you go from $ab=cd$ and $a=m\alpha$, $b=m\beta$ to $b\alpha=d\beta$?

Comment: Hint: $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = (a+b)^2+(c-d)^2$

Comment: @Don Thousand: I thought of that also, and used it as the basis for my proof, so I upvoted your comment.

Comment: $ab=cd$ implies that the vectors $\vec{u}=(a,c)$ and $\vec{v}=(b,d)$ are parallel (=linearly dependent over $\Bbb{Q}$, hence over $\Bbb{Z}$). Therefore they are both integer multiples of $\vec{w}=\dfrac{\gcd(a,b)}a\vec{u}$. The claim follows from this as $||\vec{w}||^2$ is a factor of both $||\vec{u}||^2$ and $||\vec{v}||^2$.

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{array}\\
n
&=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\\
&=a^2+b^2+2ab+c^2+d^2-2cd\\
&=(a+b)^2+(c-d)^2\\
&=a^2+b^2-2ab+c^2+d^2+2cd\\
&=(a-b)^2+(c+d)^2\\
\end{array}
$

If
$a+b=c+d$
and
$a-b=c-d$
then
$a=c$ and $b=d$
so
$n=2(a^2+b^2)
$
so $n$ is not prime.

If
$a+b\ne c+d$
and
$a-b\ne c-d$
then
$n$ can be written
as the sum of two squares
in two different ways
and so is not prime.

Comment: If a+b = c-d then $n = 2(a+b)^2$ is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

We have $d=\frac{ab}{c}.$

Thus, $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}=\frac{(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)}{c^2}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes sir good idea

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,d)=e,\dfrac aA=\dfrac dD=e\ge1$ so that $(A,D)=1$

Similarly let $(b,c)=f, \dfrac bB=\dfrac cC=f;(B,C)=1$

$ab=cd\implies AB=CD$

$B=\dfrac{CD}A\implies A$ divides $C$

$D=\dfrac{AB}C\implies C$ divides $A$

$\implies A=\pm  C\implies B=\pm D$

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=e^2C^2+e^2D^2+f^2D^2+f^2C^2=(C^2+D^2)(e^2+f^2)$

Both factors are clearly $>1$

Comment: Very nice sir , thank you

Answer (score 0):

the intermediate conclusion from what you wrote is 
$$ m^2 \alpha \beta = cd $$
which does not seem to help.

**Start over** with
$$ g = \gcd(a,c), $$
$$  a = g \alpha \; , $$
$$  c = g \gamma \; .   $$
First, 
$$  \gcd(\alpha, \gamma) = 1 $$
From $ab=cd$ we have $g \alpha b = g \gamma d,$ so
$$ \alpha b = \gamma d. $$
Since $\alpha,\gamma$ are coprime, we must have $\alpha |d.$ Write
$$  d = h \alpha. $$ Then
$$ \alpha b = \gamma \alpha h \; , $$
$$  b = h \gamma $$ Together
$$ a = g \alpha, \; \; b = h \gamma, \; \; c = g \gamma, \; \; d = h \alpha \; .  $$
Then $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = a^2 + c^2 + d^2 + b^2 = g^2 (\alpha^2 + \gamma^2) + h^2 (\alpha^2 + \gamma^2) = (g^2 + h^2) (\alpha^2 + \gamma^2)  $$
Then $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2  = (g^2 + h^2) (\alpha^2 + \gamma^2)  $$

Comment: I'd like to add that this is an equivalence: $ab=cd$ iff there exist $x,y,z,t$ such that $a=xy$, $b=zt$, $c=xt$, $d=yz$.